# How to determine the different format of an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x, formatting

Python code: I have an array of strings with some having split with '-' and some are not, and some splits are at different location with in the string. I want to identify and group the strings that follow a certain format like XXXX-XXX-XX. have anyone solved this kind of list?

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: it is in Python

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to tag your question with Python so people can find your question. Also I would recommend adding some example inputs/outputs, and the code you have written to solve the problem